# Query with optional/conditional join between 2 tables

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, linq, join

```
ResourceTranslation
--------------------------------------------
ID                          binary(16)      |
ShortStringResourceID       binary(16)      |
LocaleName                  varchar(50)     |
TranslatedText              text            |
--------------------------------------------


ShortStringresource
--------------------------------------------
ID                          binary(16)      |
PrimaryLocaleName           varchar(50)     |
ContentText                 varchar(255)    |
--------------------------------------------
```

I want to achieve an equivalent of the following SQL in LINQ to SQL:

```
SELECT (CASE p.PrimaryLocaleName WHEN 'en-GB' THEN p.ContentText ELSE t.ContentText END)
FROM shortstringresource p 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN resourcetranslation t ON t.ShortStringResourceID = p.ID 
WHERE p.ContentText = "Question 1 English Text"
AND (p.PrimaryLocaleName = 'en-GB' OR t.LocaleName = 'en-GB')
LIMIT 1;
```

Or kind of join the following 2 queries into 1:

```
var qry1 = (from p in I18nObjects.ShortStringResources
            where (p.PrimaryLocaleName == "en-GB" && p.ContentText == "my text")
            select p.ContentText);

var qry2 = (from t in I18nObjects.ResourceTranslations
           where t.LocaleName == "en-GB" 
           join p in I18nObjects.ShortStringResources on t.ShortStringResourceID equals p.ID
           select t.TranslatedText);
```

Comment: you can perform a left outer join in LINQ : http://smehrozalam.wordpress.com/2009/06/10/c-left-outer-joins-with-linq/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to consider ordering before selecting.

```
var results = (from p in ShortStringResources 
   join t in ResourceTranslations on p.ID equals t.ShortStringResourceID into xy
   from x in xy.DefaultIfEmpty()
   where p.ContentText == "Question 1 English Text" &&
        (p.PrimaryLocaleName == "en-GB" || x.LocaleName == "en-GB")
   select new {
      newField = p.PrimaryLocaleName == "en-GB"? p.ContentText : x.ContentText
   }).ToList().Take(1);
```

Comment: Ok you do need the left outer join otherwise if there is a row in the ShortStringresources but not in the ResourceTranslation table I still want to pick that up.

Comment: `var results = (from p in I18nObjects.ShortStringResources 
                    join t in I18nObjects.ResourceTranslations on p.ID equals t.ShortStringResourceID
                    where p.ContentText == content && (p.PrimaryLocaleName == locale || t.LocaleName == locale)
                    select new {
                        newField = p.PrimaryLocaleName == locale ? p.ContentText : t.TranslatedText
                    }).ToList().Take(1);`  This only works if there is always a corresponding record in ResourceTranslation table because of the absense of left outer join.

Comment: @Kaf: Don't you need a .DefaultEmpty() in there to complete the OUTER JOIN?

Comment: @PieterGeerkens, it is there `from x in xy.DefaultIfEmpty()` before `where` clause

Comment: @Kaf: Thanks there is one minor mistake equal should be equals .. rest it works great.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i understand your question you want to select a Translation for a specific text and if this translation doesn't exists you want the original value. So a left join would be the right way to do it.

I would do it like this:

```
var result = ( from p in I18nObjects.ShortStringresource
               where p.PrimaryLocaleName == "en-GB"
               where p.ContentText == "my text"

               from t in I18nObjects.ResourceTranslations
                 on p.ID equals t.ShortStringResourceID
               into tJoinData
               from tJoinRecord in tJoinData.DefaultIfEmpty( )
               where tJoinRecord.LocaleName == "en-GB"

               select tJoinRecord.TranslatedText ?? p.ContentText ).First( );
```

(but maybe i misunderstood your question)

Comment: this query does not compile

Comment: @user1984695 whats the error message? maybe the typo of `DefaultIfEmpty`? it was spelled wrong

Comment: Expression is not allowed in a subsequent from clause in a query expression. Type inference failed in the call to 'Select Many'